# How to remove existing partition that used to be primary installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I had a serious problem with my install earlier this week that went from bad to worse and lead me to just reinstall 13.10 again on the same drive but partitioned in half. So now I have a 240 GB SSD split into about 110GB for each install.

I'm just about done copying all my important files over from the old partition and everything is running smoothly again on the new partition so now I'm looking to resize the new primary partition back to full size and blow away the entire old one.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this without making sure that I don't lose any data and also making sure that the new primary partition remains properly associated with the GRUB boot loader as currently GRUB sort of ignores the GRUB file on the second (new) partition and only reads the GRUB menu from the first partition.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm generally not a noob and am comfortable in the command line, just not when it comes to things that might blow away wrong partitions and MBRs. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't grow a partition backwards. IMO, you should format this 2nd partition as ext4, copy all your files to it (using live CD) and then, after you format the first partition again, you use the first partition as /home (without formating it!)

Comment: Read "you use the first partition as /home" as "you use the **2nd** partition as /home"

Answer (score 0):

One option is not to delete it at all. I shuffle partitions regularly, and when I'm done copying, I boot into a livecd, run gparted (a gui partitioner), and resize my nearly empty partition to as small as it will go... you can either resize one or more of your other partitions to recover the space, or allocate the spare space to a new partition.

Comment: This sounds like the most reasonable answer. And something I'm completely comfortable with. Any idea how to convince GRUB to run off the second partition instead of the first one?